# Form submission via jquery excludes a field

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, httpwebrequest

So... currently, the form submission looks like this:
[image]

suggested_text is empty. 
but I use jquery to set the `textarea` when the form is done loading.
So... even if the rich text editor didn't work at all, shouldn't it still be submitting that value that I set it to?

Note:
on the actual form, I can see the suggested text's default text.
Le Proof of default text loading in form:
[image]

Code:

```
<% form_remote_tag :url => {:action => :ajax_update, :controller => :changes},
                :html => {:id => "modify_form"} do %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :id, @change[:id] %>           
    <div class="suggested_text_container">
        <%= text_area_tag :suggested_text, :class=>"rl_text_form", :label=>false, :resizable => false, :style => "display: none"%>
    </div>                      
    <div class="submit_container">
        <%= link_to_remote "Modify Request", 
            :url => { :action => :ajax_update,
                :controller => :changes },
            :submit => "modify_form",
            :before => "set_content_to_textarea();",
            :html => {:id => "comment_submit",
            :class => "redline_submit"} %>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $j(function(){
            $j("#suggested_text").html("<%= @change.suggested_text %>");
            rl_editors = $j('.rl_text_form').rte();
        });

        function set_content_to_textarea(){
            $j('#modify_form #suggested_text').html(
                $j("#modify_form iframe").contents().find(".proposal").html());
        }
    </script>
<% end %>
```

I'm using Rails 2.3.8

Comment: Wouldn't you want to set the value of the text area?

Comment: :value => "value" doesn't work for textareas =\  I don't /think/ that's the problem though. =\

Comment: I meant in the JS where you're now using `.html()`. Also, [this](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/154952). (2nd arg can be value, IIRC.)

Comment: oh, well what do you know. I was going to be like "nu-uh, textarea's only work with .html()", so I tried to find a source, but then I found that .val() works. =\ My problem is solved. =\

Comment: Yep :) Also, since you're going by id, there's no need to specify both--use the same selector you use in the dom-ready function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the value through **val()** instead of html() It should change It's value and markup.

```
$j('#modify_form #suggested_text').val(..
```